# How to loop through each value

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-2.0

So I have this .inc file which has a set of `<li>` elements like

```
<li class="closed"><a title="x" href="x.html">x</a></li>
<li class="closed"><a title="y" href="y.html">y</a></li>
<li class="closed"><a title="z" href="a.html">z</a></li>
```

I'm able to get each value using the following XSL code:

```
<xsl:variable name="vText" select="unparsed-text('/abc/abcd/leftnav.inc')"/>
<xsl:variable name="vExtracted" as="xs:token*">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="$vText" regex="&gt;([^&lt;]*)&lt;/a&gt;" flags="m">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:variable>
```

So now if I want to print each value I use something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$vExtracted[1]"/><br/>
<xsl:value-of select="$vExtracted[2]"/><br/>
<xsl:value-of select="$vExtracted[3]"/><br/>
.
.
and so on which outputs like:
x
y
z
```

My question is how can I just loop through $vExtracted and print all the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$vExtracted">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
</xsl:for-each >
```